# How to open jupyter notebook from any desired location?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I want to open the jupyter notebook from another location? Currently, the jupyter notebook is getting opened from the default folder location. But I want to open it from a different folder just for this once and not every time. Is it possible to do so without changing the default location?

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. Open your Juypter notebook
2. Click "New"
3. Click "Terminal"
4. Move to where you want by typing something like `cd C:\Target_directory\`
5. Then type `Jupyter Notebook`, a new Jupyter Notebook will open

But I think you should be able to find existing answers to your question somewhere else. That is probably why your question got downvoted.

Comment: I tried the same but still it is opening from the default location.

Comment: Thanks but I have fixed the issue. I generated a new config file by using `jupyter notebook --generate-config` and after that I tried your solution it worked.